# delete every line which has double entries with a regex

Tags: regular-expression

I have a bunch of csv files which look sort of like this:

```
date,receiver,client,article_id,amount
5-12-2019,thomas,thomas,2,23
5-12-2019,joe,joe,2,14
6-12-2019,tobias,bob,4,1
```

now I would like to search for every line where receiver and client are identical.
Can this be done with a regex search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to skip the first column (comma delimited) and search for everything, where the second column is the same as the third column.

As a regex this can be written like this:

```
^[^,]*,\zs\([^,]*\),\1
|  |  |  | |  |   || └ Same match as what was captured
|  |  |  | |  |   |└   Comma 
|  |  |  | |  |   └    End of captured group
|  |  |  | |  └        Any number of non-commas
|  |  |  | └           Capture the following
|  |  |  └             Start the match here
|  |  └                A comma
|  └                   Any number of non-commas
└                      Start of line
```

You can use `:set hls` to have a visual indication of what lines match the pattern.

Now if you want to delete those matching lines, you can simply use a `:g` command, which basically means, do for all lines that match a certain pattern:

```
:g/^[^,]*,\zs\([^,]*\),\1/d
```

Or, if you already have the pattern in the search register (e.g. all matching lines are already colored), you can even simplify this call to:

```
:g//d
```

Which means, delete all the lines that match the last entered search pattern.